# Has Savitar become slower?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In S3 ep. 15 - The Wrath of Savitar- when Savitar is released, he doesn't seem to be moving that much faster than Barry, and Barry even takes him on. Jessie Quick seems to be able to give him a run for his money in the next episode too.

But the first time we saw Savitar (when Wally ended up in a cocoon)

from Barry's point of view, it looked like he was moving just as fast he does from the point of view of normal humans when they see him run.

This could of course be because he was in 'normal mode' (when he isn't using his powers), but in the next episode,  Cisco says "it seems [Savitar's] appearing and reappearing all over the city at once and that's impossible. He can't be moving that fast." And those are words from somebody who works with the Flash on a daily basis.

In Season 3 Episode 9, Barry is again no match for Savitar- along with Wally

So has Savitar become slower ever since he was released or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, he always traveled at the same speed - speed of bad plot. _</obligatory>_

Comment: "Jesse, I have plans for you". Maybe that explained why he is not full speed in Ep.15. Also, we don't know yet his full powers and his exact connection to the Speed Force. Wait and see. Reverse-Flash and Zoom, as well as Barry, had somewhat inconsistent speed too.

Answer (score 3):

When we first see Savitar he is using the philosopher's stone to escape temporally from the speed force.  In essence he is jumping in and out of the speed for and teleportating around the city.  Once he is fully out of the speed force he can no longer jump in and out of the speed force and is reduced to his regular speed.

> We later learn that Savitar is one of Barry's time remnants and at this point it makes sense that one should not be faster than the other.

Comment: Although the armour is helpful in reducing friction even more than Barry's Flash suit... hence the blue lightning...

Comment: That is what he claims but once Savitar is not in the speed force anymore he is not much faster than Barry.

Comment: True, but even slower when not wearing the armour... almost of equal speed compared to Barry :P